# Is it possible to add UIGestureRecognizer for single word in UILabel?

Tags: ios6, uilabel

Is it possible to add UIGestureRecognizer for single word in UILabel?

Comment: gesture is depend on area cover by controller added of UIGesture ,like in your case UILabel have any text or not not depend on it . it may be 1 or 100... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add UIGestureRecognizer for single word in UILabel by using TTTAttributedLabel.

https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel